# VBA - multiple file open, copy and paste to new file

Tags: vba

VBA - As the typical question starts, I am NEW (brand new) to VBA. I want to open a spreadsheet that will allow me to open multilple files (undetermined number) from one folder. It will then select certain cells from each file, copy and paste them into my original spreadsheet. Of course, then close all of the other files.

Comment: Are you copying the same cells from each file, or is each file different?

Comment: Yes, each open file will the same cells being copied. The file that we are copying to will be pasted in the other cells but, the same on this sheet. We need to copy (for example C1, C10, C11, C34, D1) from each sheet and paste them to A1,B1,C1,E1,H1 (again for example)

Answer (score 0):

See if this will help.  Because we're copying from an irregular (non-contiguous) range, it's a bit difficult to copy to another irregular range.  So for that reason, the target range is "A1,B1,C1,D1,E1, etc", instead of "A1,B1,C1,E1,H1, etc".  If that doesn't work for you, we'll need to try something a bit more elaborate.

```
Sub copyMultFiles()
    Dim rS As Range, rT As Range, Cel As Range
    Dim wBs As Workbook 'source workbook
    Dim wS As Worksheet 'source sheet
    Dim wT As Worksheet 'target sheet
    Dim x As Long 'counter
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arrFiles() As String 'list of source files
    Dim myFile As String 'source file

    '    change these to suit requirements
    Const csMyPath As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\Dave\Desktop\TestFolder\" 'source folder
    Const csMyFile As String = "*.xls" 'source search pattern
    Const csSRng As String = "$C$1,$C$10,$C$11,$C$34,$D$1" 'source range
    Const csTRng As String = "$A$1" 'target range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '   target sheet
    Set wT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'change to suit
    '   clear sheet
    wT.Cells.Clear 'may not want this, comment out!!!

'   aquire list of files
    ReDim arrFiles(1 To 1)
    myFile = Dir$(csMyPath & csMyFile, vbNormal)
    Do While Len(myFile) > 0
        arrFiles(UBound(arrFiles)) = myFile
        ReDim Preserve arrFiles(1 To UBound(arrFiles) + 1)
        myFile = Dir$
    Loop
    ReDim Preserve arrFiles(1 To UBound(arrFiles) - 1)

    Set rT = wT.Range(csTRng)

    ' loop thru list of files
    For x = 1 To UBound(arrFiles)
        Set wBs = Workbooks.Open(csMyPath & arrFiles(x), False, True) 'open wbook
        Set wS = wBs.Worksheets(1) 'change sheet to suit

        c = 0
        Set rS = wS.Range(csSRng)
        'copy source range to current target row
        For Each Cel In rS
            Cel.Copy rT.Offset(, c) 'next column
            c = c + 1
        Next Cel

        wBs.Close False
        Set rT = rT.Offset(1) 'next row
        DoEvents
    Next x 'next book

    Erase arrFiles

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```